# titanium alloy onClick parameters

Tags: view, controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

first of all: I am practicing with titanium, this are just my first "Hello World" apps to get confident with the framework, so any suggestion would be strongly appreciated.

I have this simple view:

```
        <ScrollView id="grid" dataCollection="pictures">
            <View class="single-item" title="{title}" author="{author}" desc="{desc}" onClick="showPic">
                <ImageView class="thumb" image="/images/thumb-stock-1.jpg" />
                <Label class="title" text="{title} by {author}" />
                <Label class="desc" text="{desc}" />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Clicking on each item I call the function showPic() defined in my controller, and that's ok. But I would like to pass some parameters to that function, that are {title}, {author} and {desc}, so that I can handle them and "print" them on a new detail view for each specific item. With TableView it was easy (I just put: event.source -> title, event.source -> author ... inside my controller and I could read that table row data), but with my view that seems not work.

so my questions are:
1) how can I pass that parameters from VIEW:  to CONTROLLER showPic()
2) generally speaking, if there is a better view to list some objects and opening each one with a click, just tell me how so that I can learn something more :D (PS: I cannot use tableView because my layout does not fit with this kind view)

---- EDIT: here follows my full code

index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="pictures"/>
    <NavigationWindow id="navGroupWin">
        <Window class="container" title="La mia galleria">
            <View class="arrow arrow-up"><Label text="UP" /></View>

            <ScrollView id="grid" dataCollection="pictures">
                <View class="single-item" title="{title}" author="{author}" desc="{desc}" onClick="showPic">
                    <ImageView class="thumb" image="/images/thumb-stock-1.jpg" />
                    <Label class="title" text="{title} by {author}" />
                    <Label class="desc" text="{desc}" />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>

            <View class="arrow arrow-down"><Label text="DOWN" /></View>

        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

showPic from index.js:

```
function showPic(event) {

    var pic = event.source;
    var args = {
        title: pic.title,
        desc: pic.desc,
        author: pic.author
    };
    var picView = Alloy.createController("detail", args).getView();

    if (OS_IOS) {$.navGroupWin.openWindow(picView);}
    if (OS_ANDROID) {picView.open();}

}
```

detail.xml:

```
<Alloy> 
    <Window class="container">
        <View layout='vertical'>
            <Label id="titleLabel"></Label>
            <Label id="descLabel"></Label> 
            <Label id="authorLabel"></Label>
        </View>
    </Window> 
</Alloy>
```

detail.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
$.titleLabel.text = args.title || 'Default Title';
$.descLabel.text = args.desc || 'Default desc';
$.authorLabel.text = args.author || 'Default author';
```

when I click on each item of the index, my source.title, source.author and source.desc seems to be empty, and on the detail window I got back only 'Default' values

Comment: Can You provide your js code? e.source should be working

Comment: thanks, I edited my first post with the full code!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this on the view file level.

What I would try is to assign ids to every view element (this is a general technique) and fully deploy all my click listeners inside the controller file, removing all onClick commands from view.

So:

1. Set `id="myview"` along with `class="single-item"` in your View
2. In your controller try

   `$.myview.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       showPic(e.title, e.author, e.desc)
   });`

Comment: thanks, but I got back a runtime error ($.myview is 'undefined'). maybe because of multiple objects with same ID?

(it works if I set id="myview" on a single item, not if I use it inside a loop with multiple items)

Comment: @btb84 - ID's have to be unique on each page - classes can be used in several places (as you know from traditional web and css). You could specify the onClick event in the markup with a call to the function for each element you want to trigger the event on - and then check the event object that is parsed as an argument to that function. Try to debug it to see what information is available to you...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it goes wrong somewhere else, but stripped down like this it works:

index.html

```
<Alloy>

        <Window id="test">          
            <ScrollView id="grid" layout="vertical">
                <View class="single-item" width="250" height="250" backgroundColor="blue" title="title" author="author" desc="desc" onClick="showPic">                   
                </View>
                <View class="single-item" width="250" height="250" backgroundColor="red" title="red" author="red" desc="red" onClick="showPic">                   
                </View>
                <View class="single-item" width="250" height="250" backgroundColor="yellow" title="yellow" author="yellow" desc="yellow" onClick="showPic">                   
                </View>
                <View class="single-item" width="250" height="250" backgroundColor="green" title="green" author="green" desc="green" onClick="showPic">                   
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </Window>

</Alloy>
```

index.js

```
function showPic(event) {
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(event.source));    
}

$.test.open();
```